# Convert from String to JsonArray using gson

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I would like to know how to convert a linear String (on mysql) into gson JsonArray.

So to resume:

```
"{\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":22,\"class\":\"mca\"}"
```

-> `{"name":"john","age":22,"class":"mca"}` (As JsonArray using gson)

Thank you very much <3

Comment: What have you tried? I mean, I *hope* you tried searching the web, and found a gazillion examples for how to invoke Gson, so in what way did that not work out for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to UNESCAPE String while converting java object to JSON string using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706849/how-to-unescape-string-while-converting-java-object-to-json-string-using-jackson)

Comment: Use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson` method. See: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING while using Gson library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178300/java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-array-but-was-string-while-using/55178991#55178991) and [How to transfer escaped JSON lines to list of beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089762/how-to-transfer-escaped-json-lines-to-list-of-beans/55092560#55092560) related questions.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
import com.google.gson.*;

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement tradeElement = parser.parse(yourString);
JsonArray jsonArray = tradeElement.getAsJsonArray();
System.out.println(jsonArray);
```